# Passing a function as a parameter to an iterating function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Reading Eloquent Javascript and one of the examples is

```
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

let labels = [];
repeat(5, x => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${x + 1}`); //what is happening here?
});

console.log(labels);
// → ["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]
```

Can someone explain how the iteration in the repeat call is working? We are creating a function (x) and passing it in as the action, but how is it aware of what iteration it is on and where does the numeric value that is being pushed to the array come from?

Comment: `action(i)` <- i (the current iteration) is passed into the action.

Comment: it's not aware persay, it just gets x passed in as an argument

Comment: Also `x` is not the function. It's a parameter. It might help writing it as `repeat(5, function(x) { ... })`

Comment: Notice the text `Unit ${x + `}` is surrounded by a tick rather than a single quote.  That is a template literal. ${... } allows you to make a reference to a scoped variable.

Comment: The function referenced as `action` is `x => { labels.push('Unit ${x + 1}');}` (template literal tick marks changed to single quotes for formatting. Those have to be ticks to work)   `x` is the argument passed into this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a couple of steps back and look at a simpler example.

This is the function you want to call multiple times:

```
function doSomething(x) {
  labels.push(`Unit ${x + 1}`);
}
```

It takes an argument which it uses to create a string, and pushes that string to an array.

Of course this is easy to do with a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  doSomething(i);
}
```

It should be obvious here that we pass the loop variable (`i`) to our function, which is assigned to parameter `x`. It's the same as doing:

```
doSomething(0);
doSomething(1);
...
```

This code is not reusable though. Say we want to call the function a different number of times, not just (and always) five times.
We can put the loop in a function itself, taking the number of times as a parameter:

```
function repeat(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    doSomething(i);
  }
}
```

Now we can call the function as `repeat(5)` or `repeat(10)` and it will call `doSomething` that many times.

However, now we want to call another function multiple times. We could create a second `repeat` function (with a different name of course), but that is not ideal.
Instead of referring to `doSomething` directly in `repeat`, we can change `repeat` to accept a second parameter whose value should be a function value. This is possible because functions are values like any other in JavaScript:

```
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}
```

Now we can reuse `repeat` to call any function we want:

```
repeat(5, doSomething)
repeat(10, doSomethingElse)
```

And that's what the code above is doing.